# Rails 5 rendering extra spaces in check_box_tag labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, css

I really cannot find a fix for this, I'm sure you can direct me to a solution.
I want to have a line of check boxes one for each day of the week to schedule training sessions on selected week days, the code in my controller is:

```
# GET /eventos/forma_prog
def forma_prog
  @entrenadores = User.all
  @dias = ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mie", "Jue", "Vie", "Sab"]
end
```

My form code is:

```
<div class="well">
  <%= label_tag :dias %>
  <div class="form-group checkbox-inline">
    <% @dias.each do |day| %>
      <%= day %><%= check_box_tag 'dias[]', day, checked = false %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

the HTML generated is this:

```
<div class="form-group checkbox-inline">
"                                                                  
                                                 Dom"
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" id="dias_" value="Dom">
"                                                                  
                                                 Lun"
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" id="dias_" value="Lun">
"                                                                  
                                                 Mar"
<input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" id="dias_" value="Mar">
```

and so on. Don't need to tell you the too many extra spaces Rails is generating in the string are ruining my sanity and my form,
[image: Rendered]

the question is how can I avoid/get rid of those unwanted spaces?

I'm using Rails-Bootstrap, this is the style code I get from the browser's  (Chrome) developer tools for that element:

```
 .checkbox-inline {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-weight: normal;
        cursor: pointer;
   }
  custom.self-d93…ss?body=1:3933
 .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
   }
```

As I am trying to solve this, I did chage the form code to:

```
<div class="well">
  Dias
  <div class="form-group checkbox-inline">
    <% @dias.each do |day| %>
      <%= label_tag day, day, class: "checkbox-inline" %><%= check_box_tag 'dias[]', day, checked = false %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Still not working...

Comment: Those spaces are harmless, the problem should be in the styling. Please share relevant CSS styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gerry's comments I found the solution to my problem, it is in the CSS so I did change the code to:

```
<div class="well">
    <% @dias.each_with_index do |day, index| %>
      <%= label_tag day, day, class: "checkbox-inline nopadding"; %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'dias[]', index, checked = false, class: "nopadding" %>  |
    <% end %>
</div>
```

and then defined the .nopadding class in my custom.scss file like this:

```
.nopadding {
   padding: 1px !important;
   margin: 3px !important;
   width: inherit;
 }
```

Thank you =)